# Why multi threading speed is not efficient in my code?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

For some reasons multi threading is not efficient in my code.

My code gets a token from a txt file and sends a post request with that token.

And i don't understand why multi threading is not efficient in my code.

It took 2.7 seconds to make 3 post requests.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import time
url_list = [
    "https://www.google.com/api/"
]

tokens = set()
with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()
    for line in file_lines:
        tokens.add(line.strip())

token_data = {"token": None}
def makerequest(url):
    for token in tokens:
        token_data["Token"] = token
        html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=token_data)
        print(html.text)

start = time()

processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200) as executor:
    for url in url_list:
        processes.append(executor.submit(makerequest, url))

for task in as_completed(processes):
    print(task.result())


print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
```

2.7 seconds to send 3 post requests i don't think it is good for multi threading.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please edit the question & add the required details in the body.

Comment: Edited it,it is not efficient.

Comment: Have you debugged how long each individual request took? Try logging the time taken by the `post` inside the `makerequest` function

Comment: 0.6 seconds/request

Comment: The thing is it waits for the request to be made and only after make another request

Comment: Your code only appears to submit one callable to the ThreadPoolExecutor, because you only have one URL. Are you asking why the executor cannot parallelise a single task?

Comment: Yes,i would like to do parallel tasks if i have 50 threads 1 thread to make a request with a different token from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't have any special insight into or control over the callables that you submit to it. It can't change how they behave. What it *can* do is start the callables passed to it on separate threads *from each other.* Let's have a look at your example:

You have one URL and some quantity of tokens. Every call to `makerequest` will make a number of requests in series, each one starting after the previous has completed, one for each token. It doesn't use multithreading in any way - whatever thread `makerequest` is called on, that's the thread that makes all of the requests, one after another.

You loop once per URL - which is to say, you do this only once at all (since you have only one URL) - and invoke `executor.submit`, telling it to call `makerequest` for that particular URL. It can do so on a thread in the thread pool, but because you only tell it to make *one* call, it's only going to make use of one thread. That single thread will call `makerequest` once, and that invocation of `makerequest` will make a number of requests all on that same thread, one after another.

If you want the requests to be made in parallel, you will need to break things up more. You could, for example, extract the loop from inside `makerequest` and make it take a URL *and* a token. Then you can submit every separate combination of URL and token to the executor separately. As a rough example:

```
def makerequest(url, token):
    token_data = {"token": token}
    html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=token_data)
    print(html.text)

# ...

processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200) as executor:
    for url in url_list:
        for token in tokens:
            processes.append(executor.submit(makerequest, url, token))
```

---

Minor notes: You use `"token"` and `"Token"` interchangeably as keys in your dictionary. That's a recipe for confusion - you should figure out which is correct and stick to it. You also create a global variable `token_data` and then modify it inside `makerequest`. This is disastrous with threads - you can't guarantee that one thread won't modify it while another is using it. You should not modify data structures shared between threads - instead create a new token_data as a local variable every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it and helping me :) appreciate your time